# Numba: vectorize standard SciPy ufunc's and numpy.sum() syntax error

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am relatively new to using `numba`, and I would like to use it to make my array calculations as efficient as possible. The function in question is a combination of several concepts in the numba documentation.

I am using a unitary function in the Scipy library

`scipy.special.eval_laguerre(n, x, out=None) = <ufunc 'eval_laguerre'>`

which evaluates a Laguerre polynomial L_n(x) at a point n.

**Question 1:** The Numba documentation clearly states how to use the decorator `@vectorize` to optimize a ufunc the user has written. http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.12/ufuncs.html#generalized-ufuncs

Is there a standard procedure to do this with ufunc provided by python libraries?

**Question 2:** I would like to evaluate L_n(x) for each entry of a matrix, for an array of n values in an array. I then must sum these values, using the expression:

`result = np.sum( [eval_laguerre(n, matrix) for n in array], axis=0)`

where I have used `import numpy as np`.

If I were to use broadcasting, I would instead evaluate:

`result = np.sum( eval_laguerre( array[:, None, None], matrix ), axis=0)`

where the `axis=0` denotes which dimension to sum.

I would like to use '@jit' to compile this section, but I am unsure what the procedure is for `'numpy.sum()`. At the moment, the above expression with the `@jit` expression gives a syntax error.

```
result = np.sum( eval_laguerre( array[:, None, None], matrix ), axis=0)
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the correct way to use `@jit` and `np.sum()`?

EDIT: In response to @hpaulj:

My thought was `numba` could optimize the for loop, i.e.

```
for n in array: 
    eval_laguerre(n, matrix)
```

Is this possible at all? If not with `numba`, then with what? `Pythran`?

Comment: Don't most, if not all, of the `numba` examples involve Python for loops?  It can translate and compile your OWN code.  It does nothing with existing Python and numpy functions, especially ones that are already written in C.  `eval_laguerre` and `sum` are already compiled; there's no Python code for numba to rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make this more concrete:

A sample array, which I'll use for both `n` and `x` (you can choose more realistic values):

```
In [782]: A=np.arange(12.).reshape(3,4)
```

The version, making full use of the `ufunc` broadcasting abilties

```
In [790]: special.eval_laguerre(A[:,None,:],A[None,:,:]).shape
Out[790]: (3, 3, 4)
```

Or summing:

```
In [784]: np.sum(special.eval_laguerre(A[:,None,:],A[None,:,:]),0)
Out[784]: 
array([[  3.00000000e+00,  -1.56922399e-01,  -4.86843034e-01,
          7.27719156e-02],
       [  1.37460317e+00,  -4.47492284e+00,   5.77714286e+00,
         -9.71780654e-01],
       [ -1.76222222e+01,   7.00178571e+00,   5.55396825e+01,
         -1.32810866e+02]])
```

equivalent with a list comprension inside the `sum`:

```
In [785]: np.sum([special.eval_laguerre(n,A) for n in A],0)
Out[785]: 
array([[  3.00000000e+00,  -1.56922399e-01,  -4.86843034e-01,
          7.27719156e-02],
       [  1.37460317e+00,  -4.47492284e+00,   5.77714286e+00,
         -9.71780654e-01],
       [ -1.76222222e+01,   7.00178571e+00,   5.55396825e+01,
         -1.32810866e+02]])
```

Or an explicit loop:

```
In [786]: x=np.zeros_like(A)    
In [787]: for n in A:
    x += special.eval_laguerre(n, A)
```

The last version has a chance of compiling with `numba`.

In simple time tests, the ufunc broadcasting is faster:

```
In [791]: timeit np.sum([special.eval_laguerre(n,A) for n in A],axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.8 µs per loop

In [792]: timeit np.sum(special.eval_laguerre(A[:,None,:],A[None,:,:]),0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.9 µs per loop
```

My guess is that a numba version will improve on the comprehension version and the explicit loop, but probably not get faster than the broadcasting one.

Comment: I never thought of running those tests. Huh. That's surprising to me. Broadcasting is in general faster.

Comment: This does not answer to the original question: "how to use `numba.vectorize` with already written ufuncs?"

Comment: A partial answer is better than none. :)